# Must a software be written in the same language as its API?

Tags: c#

I've bought a commercial software but I don't know how it was built (i.e. what language was used to build it), however, I could create an API in C# that communicates with this software. Does that mean the software must be written in C# as well? If not, what are the chances that it is written in C# (good or bad)?

Comment: `chancesItsWrittenInCS = 1/numberOfCapableLanguages;` What's the software?

Comment: What language it's written in doesn't matter, as long as you can access it from the language *you* are writing in. (And we can't speculate on the chances are that it's written in C# - it could be written in assembly language and provide a C# wrapper, for instance.)

Comment: "Close because it is primarily opinion based"?  The headline question has an absolutely unambiguous factual answer.  The secondary question for his specific system, has an opinion based answer, but statistically the answer is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. 
And it shouldn't matter to you.

It is the case that it is generally a lot easier to write software in the same language as the API is offered, which is why it usually happens that way.  So the odds are high that what the APIs implement are vanilla with respect to the language.

OTOH, often APIs provide access to capabilities not available in the native language; in that case, clearly the implemented routine must be using something else.  Consider thread forking in C#; there's an API for it, but C#-the-base-language doesn't offer threads.  So there must be something pretty strange from the point of view of C#, behind its threading API [e.g., Windows machine code, making funny requests to Windows].